# Onclick of ImageButton in asp.net is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, imagebutton

`OnClick` event of `ImageButton` is  not working in asp.net. This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788018/aspimagebutton-not-firing-onclick-event) but all the answers do not work for me. In my case the only difference is I don't have `UpdatePanel` on my page.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <asp:DataList ID="PhotoGalleryDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><a href="#">
            <div>
               <span>
                  <asp:Label ID="idlabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AdPhotoID") %>'></asp:Label>
                   <asp:ImageButton ID="AdGallaryImageButton" runat="server" ToolTip="View Photo" CssClass="AdPhotoGallery"
                        AlternateText="Photo" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl='<%#string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("NormalImage"))) %>'
                        OnClick="AdGallaryImageButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AdPhotoID")%>' />
                </span>
            </div>
            </a></li>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</ul>
```

In the code-behind, I'm binding like this:

```
PhotoGalleryDataList.DataSource = dt1;
PhotoGalleryDataList.DataBind();
```

In `dt1` I have `NormalImage`, `IsProfileImage` and `AdPhotoID`, where `NormalImage` is a `byte array` and `IsProfileImage` is `Byte` and `AdPhotoID` is `varchar(15)`.

In `OnClick` event handler of the `ImageButton` I have:

```
protected void AdGallaryImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // breakpoint here does not get hit
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data bound controls like `DataList` or `Repeater` you should use `OnCommand` event to handle clicks:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AdGallaryImageButton" runat="server" ToolTip="View Photo" CssClass="AdPhotoGallery"
        AlternateText="Photo" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl='<%#string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("NormalImage"))) %>'
        OnCommand="AdGallaryImageButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AdPhotoID")%>' />
```

And change the signature of your event handler:

```
protected void AdGallaryImageButton_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Here you can access AdPhotoID argument via e.CommandArgument property
}
```